# Quitting a PhD program and starting another one: who is the legal owner of my research?

Tags: publications, phd, copyright, quitting

I am at the late stage of a PhD program. For some personal reasons, I have decided to quit this program and apply for a new PhD program in a different country.

I have presented one part of my research in an international conference, and I am about to submit it to a journal. Beside this paper, I have prepared 3 other papers but I have not presented them anywhere. I am the sole author of these three un-published works.

Now my question is whether it is possible to bring these researches to the next university and publish them afterwards? I am the legal owner of these researches? copyright-wise I mean.

I would be more than glad if anyone helps me in this tough situation.

PS: I would have no problem for getting recommendation letters.

Comment: Depends on the country and university, but you are likely not the legal owner of research performed using university/grant time or resources.

Comment: Sounds like you could just finish up your PhD. With good recommendation letters go get a post-doc, not another PhD program with who-knows-what hoops to jump through.

Comment: @JonCuster while that might be true in some sense, OP has unstated personal reasons for not going that route. Presumably they have weighed to pros and cons about making such a move.

Comment: @JohnColeman - True, but once one starts weighing other additional factors (like who 'owns' the research) then it is high time to re-evaluate the entire decision.

Comment: Is there actually such thing as legal ownership of research?  Copyrights and moral authorship rights for research _papers_, of course.  Research _equipment_, sure.  Research _data_, maybe.  But research per se?  What exactly are you supposed to "own"?

Comment: According to the Berne convention, authors automatically own the copyright to anything that they write.

Comment: Thanks all. What I meant is exactly the research papers. There are three papers that I have almost finished, but never presented anywhere, except to my supervisor.

Comment: I have considered finishing phD and going for a post-doc, the problem is exactly finishing the PhD. There are a lot of costs such as conference attendance, proofreading for publication (the university is in a non-English speaker country and all faculty use proofreading grant except me!), cost of submission of the thesis and so on that the department does not want to cover, while it is covered for other grant-holders. I am fed up with the discrimination, and actually I don't have saving to defray all these costs. I though somewhere else would appreciate my research better.

Answer (score 3):

Within limits, you most definitely can *bring* the old research with you and publish it. Unregulated digital data stored on a standard computer should be fine, but for example, there may be limitations on moving human subject data (even de-identified data) depending on what the IRB protocol said. If the research involved *samples* (e.g., chemical compounds) moving these may also be regulated.

You may or may not be able to use this previous work towards your dissertation. You will have to check with your new department.

Comment: all my research is based on public data, I have only used University grant which I have done teaching and supervision in compensation. Thanks for the reply